# Algebra: manipulation of expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does this:

$$a\sqrt{2}=c$$

become this?:

$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{a}{a\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a}{a \sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c \neq 0$ you can divide both sides by $c$, you get:

$$\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{c}=\frac{c}{c}=1$$

Next divide both sides by $\sqrt{2}$

$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

You know that if $a \neq 0$ you have $\displaystyle 1=\frac{a}{a}$, so $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a}{a\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$a\sqrt{2}=c$$

Divide both sides by $\sqrt{2}c$ ($c\ne0$) and clean up:

$$\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}c}=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}c}$$

$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

By multiplying both numerator and denominator on the right hand side by $a$ ($a\ne0$) we get:

$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{a}{a\sqrt{2}}$$